# html doesn't show in browser

Tags: html, browser

I need to figure out what makes the html code in this page doesn't show in browser.

http://arbsq.net/dev/out_html.htm

I checked with:

http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Farbsq.net%2Fdev%2Fout_html.htm&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

But it is not clear to me what causes the browser not to process the html code

Comment: View source in Firefox, then you'll easily be able to see. Your `HTML` is mangled. `Title` tags are not self closing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `<title/>` tag. The browser is interpreting your entire html code as the title of the page.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `<title/>` or change to `<title>Site title</title>` otherwise the hole site is interpreted as your title.

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the contents of your `<title></title>` tag to the `<body></body>` tag.  If you just remove the `<title></title>` tag like others have suggested, it will still not show because tags in the `<head></head>` tag are invisible to the end user.  The `<head></head>` tag contains scripts and links to external resources as well as information about the page for the browser.  The `<body></body>` tag should contain all of your HTML markup for the page.

Comment: The title tag has to be in the head! The problem was, that the title was self closing...

Comment: @AlexVogt Your point?  I said to move the contents of <title> not the tag itself.  His HTML markup was in the <title> and that is not where it is supposed to go.  I never said to move the <title> tag.